# Create list of lists taking every two elements from a flat list

Tags: python, list

I have the following rows in a pandas dataframe:

```
[11782,11785,11787,11787,11789,11792,11795]
[35206,35210,35212,35212,35214,35214,35216]
```

I want to create list of lists in this way:

```
[[11782,11785],[11787,11787],[11789,11792],[11795,...]
[[35206,35210],[35212,35212],[35214,35214],[35216,...]
```

How can I make this set of lists taking every two adjacent elements of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested list comprehension:

```
out = [[li[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(li), 2)] for li in s]
```

Output:

```
[[[11782, 11785], [11787, 11787], [11789, 11792], [11795]],
 [[35206, 35210], [35212, 35212], [35214, 35214], [35216]]]
```